# VB.net SOAP webservice client "Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element ..."

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

I am building a client in VB.net for calling webservices methods from a partner organisation.

I am following the guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol%28v=VS.71%29.aspx because I can't get it to work using the Web References feature of Visual Studio 2010 (when I try to do that it turns the methods from the WSDL into classes).

I have created a proxy class and can instantiate an object of that class no problem.

However, when I try to call a method which requires arguments I get this error:

```
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://api.service.apimember.emailvision.com/", local:"key"). Expected elements are <{}key>,<{}login>,<{}pwd>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? (If it's helpful I can post my code and the location of the WSDL.)

(P.S. I can get the whole thing to work fine in PHP using ZF Soap classes, but for various reasons I need to get it to work using .Net)

**Edit to add**: I have used Wireshark to examine the outgoing and incoming SOAP message to compare them with the messages being sent via SoapUI, where it all works fine.

What this has shown is that my VB client is sending a message where the namespace of the web service I am trying to access is declared as an attribute of the method, and not in the soap:envelope attributes.

Here is an example:

WORKS (produced by SoapUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:api="http://api.service.apimember.emailvision.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:openApiConnection>
```

DOESN'T WORK (produced by my VB.net code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:body>
<openApiConnection xmlns="http://api.service.apimember.emailvision.com/">
```

I think I need to declare the xmlns 'api' in the envelope element, so I need to figure out how to do this in my VB.net code.

Comment: Bit harsh just to vote the question down without giving me any feedback about why it's "poorly researched, unclear or not useful", isn't it?

Comment: "because I can't get it to work using the Web References feature of Visual Studio 2010 (when I try to do that it turns the methods from the WSDL into classes)." - what do you mean?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. What I mean is that if I right-click on my project in Visual Studio and select Add Service Reference, then select Advanced, and then select Add Web Reference, I then add the URL of the WSDL and VS identifies the Web Services. I can add a Reference now which creates a set of proxy classes, but these are the Methods of the web service, not classes, so I can't use them in my code.

Comment: For example, the method I want to use is called openApiConnection, which takes three credentials as arguments, and returns a token. In VS, openApiConnection becomes a class with three properties and no way of accessing its return value. So because of this problem I abandoned this way of proceeding and started to follow the technique described in the link I posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out I was using *System.Web.Services.Protocols*.**SoapDocumentMethodAttribute** but I should have been using *System.Web.Services.Protocols*.**SoapRpcMethodAttribute**.

Using the RPC binding style produces the message body format the remote service requires. Having read up a bit about how the attributes in the MS code I was basing my code on were affecting my output I came across this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1y9z356(v=vs.80).aspx which led me to changing the binding method, and that works.